# Python3 : using map instead of pool.map is not working any more - Multiprocessing library

Tags: python

I have used a first version of Python code that uses multiprocessing library. Everything works fine at the execution :

The part of code that interests me from this first version is :

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Compute and create new Pz_array of PPPxPPP size : only once using a boolean
    if not os.path.isfile("Pz_array"):
      ii = range(PPP)
      pool = mp.Pool(16)
      pool.map(PZ_tab, ii)
    
Photoz_tab = np.loadtxt("Pz_array")
Photoz_tab = sorted(Photoz_tab, key=lambda a_entry: a_entry[0])
Photoz_tab = np.transpose(Photoz_tab)
Photoz_tab = np.delete(Photoz_tab, 0, axis=0)
```

**Now, I would like not to use multiprocessing library and make a single process with only `map` function.** For this, I used the same code snippet than above but modified like this :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Compute and create new Pz_array of PPPxPPP size : only once using a boolean
  if not os.path.isfile("Pz_array"):
    ii = range(PPP)
    map(PZ_tab, ii)

print('here3')
Photoz_tab = np.loadtxt("Pz_array")
Photoz_tab = sorted(Photoz_tab, key=lambda a_entry: a_entry[0])
Photoz_tab = np.transpose(Photoz_tab)
Photoz_tab = np.delete(Photoz_tab, 0, axis=0)
```

With this second version, at the execution, it raises the following error :

```
here3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X2_nointerp_only_map_test.py", line 463, in <module>
    Photoz_tab = np.loadtxt("Pz_array")
  File "/Users/fab/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 968, in loadtxt
    fh = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
  File "/Users/fab/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 269, in open
    return ds.open(path, mode, encoding=encoding, newline=newline)
  File "/Users/fab/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 623, in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
OSError: Pz_array not found.
```

It seems that the following block is no more synchronous ("blocking") and I can't understand why  :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Compute and create new Pz_array of PPPxPPP size : only once using a boolean
  if not os.path.isfile("Pz_array"):
    ii = range(PPP)
    map(PZ_tab, ii)
```

Indeed, into `PZ_tab` function, I build the array `Pz_array`.

Normally, Firstly, I build the `Pz_array` into `PZ_tab` and after, I can load the file "`Pz_array`".

**But in the second version (no "`pool`" and no "`pool.map`"), everything seems to happen like the buidling of "`Pz_array`" was not performed, i.e like `map` was not blocking.**

And since this file is not created, when code reach the block (from outside of `if __name__ == '__main__':`) :

```
Photoz_tab = np.loadtxt("Pz_array")
Photoz_tab = sorted(Photoz_tab, key=lambda a_entry: a_entry[0])
Photoz_tab = np.transpose(Photoz_tab)
Photoz_tab = np.delete(Photoz_tab, 0, axis=0)
```

I`t can't find "`Pz_array`" since it has not been created by the call` map(PZ_tab, ii)`.`

Very strange and mostly, I don't understand where the error could come from.

**PS:** just in case, the function `PZ_tab` is coded like this for both versions :

```
z_alot, Photoz_tab = np.linspace(zmin, zmax, PPP), np.zeros((PPP,len(zrange)))

def PZ_tab(i):
    global j
    j=0
    while j < len(zrange):
        Photoz_tab[i][j] = Prnd(z_alot[i], zrange[j])
        j=j+1
    j=0

    outF=open("Pz_array",'a')
    while j < len(Photoz_tab[0]):
        if j == 0:
            outF.write(str("%.15e" % i))
            outF.write(str(' '))

        outF.write(str("%.15e" % Photoz_tab[i][j]))
        outF.write(str(' '))
        j=j+1

    outF.write(str('\n'))
    outF.close()
    i=i+1
```

Comment: you shouldn't be using `map` for side-effects anyway, just use a loop

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga . Welcome to the python3 world ! map alone works with python2.7, this is one of the first times where I test all my codes with python3 and I feel that I am going to get still new surprises !!

Comment: I'm quite familiar with the Python 3 world, and this is obviously what is occuring with your code, if you did some minimal debugging you would have found this out quite easily. In **any case** whether it is Python 2 or 3, **you shouldn't be using `map` here**, because your function uses side effects (indeed, it's only purpose is side effects). Just use a loop

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga . thanks for your advice : what do you mean by "**side effects**" ? I don't understand why map could be banned in my code ? Actually, before testing the code with python3 and only map alone, I was using a variant of this code with pool.map (from multiprocessing import) and it was very easy to multithread the code : in python2.7, it's a fast and easy way to parallelize the code.